# Windows won't install

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I want to install Windows XP, but this shows up and I can not go further.

[image: screenshot]

I have one hard disk. It is split up in two partition. One is primary and is full of documents. The other is logical.  I had Windows there, but now it is formatted.  I can not install Windows in logical drives, so I'm stuck here.

Comment: Yes, I do have permission.

Comment: After viewing the error it seems you should follow the instructions in message.

Comment: XP will not install onto a logical partition, change it to a primary basic partition.

Answer (score 3):

Let this be a lesson to you. XP (as well as every version of Windows forward of XP) requires a primary partition to install, you tried to install it on a logical/never-going-to-be-bootable partition. either use the primary partition to install XP, or find a way such as a linux live CD to convert the logical partition into a primary partition.

Comment: I can not use primary partition, it is full of documents. Can I i change to primary with Backtrack ? Can I do that with a backtrack live usb?

Comment: @user3882221: You can have multiple primary partitions.  Use a partitioning tool to replace the extended partition with one or more primaries plus an extended (depending on the disk size).  If the existing primary isn't full, you can defrag the free space and then shrink it to gain additional space for new partitions if you want.

Comment: How can I do that if I have no OS installed?

Comment: "XP (as well as every version of Windows forward of XP) requires a primary partition to install" - No, it requires a primary partition to ***boot***, not *install*.

Comment: @Karan but from what I've seen, Windows will refuse to install to a logical partttition

Comment: If there's no primary partition it can place its boot files in, then yes. Otherwise I can confirm [it does work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vqsFr.png).

Comment: @Karan so it does... I wonder if that drive has any LVM partitions on it

Comment: Which one, the drive in the screenshot?

Comment: @Karan the drive in the ops question

Comment: Who knows, but somehow I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you need to take to rescue your files;

1. Download [GParted](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-0.22.0-1-i586.iso) and burn it on a CD or DVD
2. Boot from disk, select default start option and when it asks you which mode you prefer, press 2 for the command-line
3. Type `sudo fdisk -l` to see a list of your partitions, lets say you have **/dev/sda1** and **/dev/sda2** as your primary partitions and **/dev/sda5** as logical
4. Type `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` to start editing your disk partitions
5. Type *d* to enter delete mode, and type the number of your logical partition (*5* for **/dev/sda5**)
6. Type *n* to create a new partition and type *p* to make it a primary partition
7. Type *p* to see the new partition table and identify the newly created partition name (it will end up being **/dev/sda3** in our example)
8. Type *w* to save your changes and exit
9. Don't forget to format your new partition as NTFS using the command `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sda3`
10. Take GParted CD out, put Windows XP CD in, reboot, install.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1 (simplest)

Delete extended partition using GParted or similar utility from a Linux/Windows LiveCD/USB (such as Hiren's), then install XP into unallocated space and it will create a primary partition and do the rest.

#### Option 2 (a bit harder)

XP onwards requires a primary active **boot** partition, but has no problems being installed to or running from a logical partition as long as the former condition is met. The simplest way to do this is to use something like GParted to create a small primary FAT32 partition, ideally at the beginning of the drive (mark it active as well while you're at it). Point XP Setup to install itself onto a logical partition and it should automatically install NTLDR and associated boot files on this primary partition.

*In case* XP fails to subsequently boot, the fix is simple. Use the XP Recovery Console from the installation media to copy NTLDR, BOOT.INI, NTDETECT.COM and NTBOOTDD.SYS (if it exists) to the small FAT32 partition, then run the [fixboot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314058)  and [bootcfg /rebuild](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291980) commands.

Windows 7 onwards has made this much simpler because it automatically creates a [separate System Reserved partition](https://superuser.com/a/915724/138343) for the bootmgr and BCD files as long as there's space on the drive, so it can be installed in a logical partition without any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do all the tricky stuff that people are suggesting and since you have boot media. use the XP CD to boot into the recovery console. you should be able to format the logical partition and either xcopy or move the files in your Primary over to the Logical. from the command line. If the recovery CD cant see or access the files then a full install of XP wont either.

Then once you are sure you have everything copied over, format the primary and install windows XP.  Though XP has been end of life'd and you would be better off with Win7 at a minimum.