# Cannot clear OverProvisoning partition after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd

My notebook comes with Windows 8. I bought Samsung SSD 840 Evo and allocated 20 GB for OverProvisioning. Then I upgraded to Windows 10 and saw that Windows created [450 MB recovery partition](https://superuser.com/a/915724/586446) using some space from OP partition. Now I need to remove OP partition because I need some space to install Linux Mint (having only Windows isn't really good thing). However Samsung Magician doesn't allow to remove it because "OP can be set or cleared only for the last accessible partition".

I could simply override this partition but there is a warning: "Using a RAW partition may damage your data." Does this warning refer to OP partition? Or can I safety delete this partition and install Linux?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You don't actually need the recovery partition, there isn't anything about it, hat can't be accessed by just using a Windows 10 installation disk.

Comment: Ok, after some tests I think it was a stupid question. OP is just an unallocated space - simply no partition there. After I created partition in Windows manager OP disappeared and when I removed it free space was reported as OP in Samsung Magician. So if anyone wants to do that with his non-Samsung SSD just make an unallocated space and you will have OverProvisioning partition. Warning refers to RAW partition which also could be shrunk.
Thanks Ramhound for answer but I think I'll better keep recovery partition because it's only 0,5GB and Windows 10 many times provided to be very unpredictable.