# What partitions on my hard drive are nessecary for imaging onto a new drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I just used macrium to clone my old 1tb platter HD to a 500gb SSD. I want to keep as much space as possible free on the SSD. Would you know what the purpose of the 884mb and 19.32GB partitions are for in the old hard drive? I think they are HP recovery partitions, but I could not find info on this online. What is the exact purpose of these partitions?

Currently I am on the top cloned partitions, and able to run without the two recovery partitions. Is it dangerous to run the OS without recovery partition on the same drive?

In the attache picture, disk 0 is the new SSD, and disk 1 is the old HD.

Thanks for your time.

[image: Hard drive partition size and type (bottom shows old internal laptop drive.)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggest the `recovery partitions` that you see on your 1 TiB drive are for recovery purposes only. They do not take part in the normal operation of the OS.

So OEMs often provide an option of transferring the recovery partion on to an external media (like DVD / ext. HDD) so that you could use that for recovery.

Just for your satisfaction, see if all that used to work before the transfer is working now too.

To answer your question

> What partitions on my hard drive are necessary for imaging onto a new drive?

I think only the **partition with the OS** and the **partitions (if any) where you store your data** are the only partitions you need for a working clone copy.

However it is recommended that you keep your recovery partitions (or the data in the recovery partitions) in some location. This can be used as and when necessary.

For more information on this topic you can see the below answer which cites various references on this subject

[What is this Recovery Partition for on a fresh installation of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/915238/what-is-this-recovery-partition-for-on-a-fresh-installation-of-windows-10?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: "are the only partitions you need for a working clone copy." - Which are which partitions exactly?  The answer to that question would be *the first three partitions....*

Comment: You mean first three partitions in **Disk 1**?

Comment: Ill transfer the recovery files over. Could you refer me to a site that would show me how to transfer the 884mb and 19.32GB images i skipped? Right now all i know is that i could use win10 disk management to shrink the live 446gb partition and then copy the other partitions over, but i dont think recovery would work if i do this.

Comment: nm macrium had an option to image that was not obvious to get to.

Comment: i wanted to have those 20gb free, but if it adds a safety net for if my os stops booting, then i guess its worth it.